# ¿Seleccionar un formulario creado mediante un array PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Mediante un `array` creo formularios con `php`, cada formulario tiene un `input` `text` el cual esta oculto *(hidden)* , quiero mostrarlo mediante un botón en cada uno de esos formularios.

Parecido a las publicaciones de facebook que para poder comentar tienes que darle click al botón "Comentar" y te aparece el inpux Text

Este es mi código `jquery`.

```
$("#mosCom").click(function(){
    $("#comend").show();
});
```

`"moscom"` es el id de los botones mostrar en cada formulario y `"comend"` es el id del input text oculto.

El problema es que todos los formularios tienen mismo id pensaba en crear un id con un contador `"moscom1"`, `"moscom2"`, pero me pregunto como podría seleccionar ese id en general con `jquery` y de ahí mostrar el `input text` correspondiente de ese formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo utilizaría clases para esto. Cada formulario tendría su class="myForm" por ej. Dentro de cada formulario tendrás el botón class="comentar". Por lo tanto, podrías hacer algo como:

**html**:

```
<form class="myForm" action="...">
    <textarea name="comentario" class="hidden"></textarea>
    <button class="comentar">Comentar</a>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".comentar").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil('textarea.comentario').show();
});
```

Esto es una aprox, depende de como tengas hecho tu html, pero en general podrás hacer referencia al parent del botón que ha llamado a la acción.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho tu codigo , este fue el resultado:

`$("[id*=mosCom]").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings('div#comend').show(); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar simplemente `$(selectorBoton).siblings(selectorCampo)` que te buscaría a todos campos que son hermanos del botón, a continuación te ilustro un ***«ejemplo»*** es obvio que deberás personalizar los selectores **selectorBoton** y **selectorCampo** usando ya sea un nombre de `clase` filtro o a través de un atributo `data-*`, puesto que no es una practica muy recomendable usar selectores tan generales para tareas tan especificas.

```js
$("textarea").hide();

$("button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings('textarea').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form action="...">
    <textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Comentar</button>
</form>
<form action="...">
    <textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Comentar</button>
</form>
<form action="...">
    <textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Comentar</button>
</form>
<form action="...">
    <textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Comentar</button>
</form>
<form action="...">
    <textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Comentar</button>
</form>
```

Espero te sea una alternativa de utilidad.